# Work done on an object from different frames

Tags: work

Consider this situation: A car is moving on a road and applies brakes. The road exerts a force $F$ on the car, due to which the car stops in $S$ meters. Clearly, the work done by the road on the car is $-FS$. But, according to Newton's third law, an equal force by the car acts on the road. And this force is also displaced by a magnitude $S$ (from the road's frame). So, does this mean, that the car does work on the road too? Also, from the car's viewpoint, the force is not displaced at all. So, from the car's frame, no work is being done. How come?

Secondly, consider a boat of mass $m$ accelerating at $a$ with respect to the water. The work done by the boat's engine on the boat is $maS$. But from the bank, it can be seen that the water is accelerating at $a$ in the opposite direction. So, from the bank frame, no force acts on the boat, so no work is being done. How is this possible?

Comment: See my answer to your other question. Remember that work is the transfer of energy. Look at your systems to see where the work is coming from and where it's going to. Remember that if you take the whole system, e.g. car + road, the net energy change, and therefore the net work, is zero.

Comment: Ah, yes. I suggest you remove your answer from my other question and repost it here where it'll be more relevant (I think you misunderstood my other question). I'll be able to accept it here.